# Upgrading Visual Studio web service project says to "convert to web application."

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web-services, web-applications

I have a Visual Studio 2003 web service project that I have to upgrade to Visual Studio 2008.  After I have run the conversion wizard, I get this message:

> You have completed the first step in
>   converting your Visual Studio .NET
>   2003 web project. To complete the
>   conversion, please select your project
>   in the Solution Explorer and choose
>   the 'Convert to Web Application'
>   context menu item.

I got this message with another project, which was originally a "web site", rather than an ASP.NET "web application".  It made sense to in that case (sort of).  Why, however, would I not just want to have this project remain a web service project?

Additionally, when I follow the instructions and select "Convert to Web Application" from the context menu, I don't get any feedback that anything has changed.  Should it have?  If so, what?

Answer (score 3):

This has been an issue since VS2005 was released. VS2005 (.Net 2.0 really) allowed partial classes to be defined, so this is how the new Web Application project template seperates designer generated code from your own.

ScottGu explains it better here: http://webproject.scottgu.com/VisualBasic/Migration/Migration.aspx

Here is a similar MSDN reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95x0y0wt.aspx

Scott walks you through the migration step by step. Instructs you on how to create partial classes and how to create seperate designer files. The process of migrating to a web application is supposed to look at your code and put all of your control definitions, etc. and put them in the designer files. If you didn't setup the partial classes and designer files up front, this is probably why you don't see anything happenning.